# Why is the support circuit for switching regulators more complex and expensive compared to linear regulators?

Tags: power-supply, voltage-regulator, switching-regulator, linear-regulator

One disadvantage with switching regulators compared to linear regulators is that the support circuitry is more complex. It involves more components and make material cost more expensive. This also makes the board harder to layout. Why can't those components be squeezed into the IC given today's technology?

Comment: I disagree with your premise (the 'more expensive' part). A big aluminum heatsink can get very pricy compared to a few-uH inductor.

Comment: I'm guessing you haven't seen POL (point-of-load) SMPSes. The commonly used ones look like this: http://www.aimtec.com/site/Aimtec/files/Datasheet/HighResolution/AM1S-Z.pdf (to pick a random example of stuff I've used in the past).

Answer (score 3):

[They can.](http://www.ti.com/product/lm2825) But there's no savings with regards to parts cost or board space, only that the regulator just "drops in" without much work.

[image]

Comment: Wow!! I thought only capacitors, resistors and transistors can be squeezed into the IC. I didn't realize that inductors can even be squeezed into the IC today. Upvoted your answer.

Comment: Just keep in mind how monstrously huge the chip is because of that.

Comment: Quick glance. Why the hell would a regulator IC need 24 pins? Some 8-bit MCUs have lesser than that!

Comment: Because you're putting 1A total through a good number of them.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams  Inside of the DIP there could be a PCB with an IC, separate a capacitor, separate inductor.

Comment: @NickAlexeev: I'm almost certain that there are a separate die and passives in the package.

Comment: That might be fun to get on a x-ray machine.

Comment: I'm not seeing in the docs of the LM2825 any claim that the inductor etc is built in some kind of monolithic process with the rest of the components. So that LM2825 is probably not a single IC anymore than the plethora of SMPS modules in a single package like http://www.aimtec.com/site/Aimtec/files/Datasheet/HighResolution/AM1S-Z.pdf etc.

Comment: @user768421 The connections to the board act as a heat sink. On top of that, they have the output adjustment and soft-start pins along with some NC pins which are probably for testing.

Answer (score 3):

Even when the inductor and capacitors are integrated they are not put on the silicon in the normal manner for ICs they are just included in an overall package to make a module.  That's why the module is so big.

In order to integrate the components like this they in general run the switching regulator at high frequency (>1MHz) to minimize the size of the inductor and capacitor.

Comment: Thanks! One thing I don't understand. Why need to run at high frequency to minimize size of inductor and capacitor?

Comment: Smaller inductor has less energy storage (one half L x I squared), so more charge/discharge cycles are needed to transfer equivalent amount of energy. Furthermore, IC-integrated inductors lack ferrite magnetic core and so have even less energy storage than external inductor.

Comment: Just noticed the TI LM2825 is in a big 24-PDIP package, so it *might* have a small torroid ferrite inductor inside... they'd need a relatively large package like that to fit that kind of component inside the epoxy mold, and have clearance to not break out of the package.

Comment: @MarkU: The LM2825 has 4.3mm thick plastic package. While that is certainly an improvement over the typical POL SMPS package, it's still not just a single IC die in that package.

Answer (score 3):

I think the accepted answer is fairly misleading. Here's a conceptual cross-section view of an POL SMPS from a smaller manufacturer. The choke (inductor) is clearly not on the die.

[image]

And further in [the same presentation](http://www.power-wide.com/pol.pdf) there are some X-rayed/decapped competitors' modules from better-known companies: [image].

You can clearly see how big the inductor is compared to everything else.